# Error during calling function

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, goerli

I need some understanding why I get errors in the following code. I try to call function getAmountOutMin to get the amount of particular token(_tokenOut) I can buy (amountOutMins) on _amountIn of token _tokenIn. But regardless of amount I specify in _amountIn(for instance, I specify 10000000000000000 WEI, that's about 0.01 WETH) I get the error.

`call to Uniswap.getAmountOutMin errored: execution reverted`

As I token_in I specify 0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6 address(WETH in Goerli), token_out  = 0x78c26A88c19ae0311e0121f7350735b842AFFd41.

I do need some help to understand what I'm doing wrong

````
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
 
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";
interface IUniswapV2Router {
  function getAmountsOut(uint256 amountIn, address[] memory path)
    external
    view
    returns (uint256[] memory amounts);
  
  function swapExactTokensForTokens(

    uint256 amountIn,
    uint256 amountOutMin,
    address[] calldata path,
    uint256 deadline
  ) external returns (uint256[] memory amounts);
}

contract Uniswap {

    address private constant uniswap_goerli = 0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f;
    address private constant WETH_Goerli = 0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6;
    address private constant ETH_Goerli = 0x8d27431c473E83611847D195d325972e80D1F4c1;



    
///call via web3
    function approve_for_uniswap(uint _amount_to_send) public payable{
        // IERC20(ETH_Goerli).approve(address(this),_amount_to_send);
        // IERC20(ETH_Goerli).transfer(address(this),_amount_to_send);
        IERC20(ETH_Goerli).approve(uniswap_goerli,_amount_to_send);

    }
    
    function _swap_token(address  _token_in,address  _token_out,uint _amountIn,uint _amountOutMin,address _to) external{
        address[] memory path;
        if (_token_in==WETH_Goerli || _token_out == WETH_Goerli){ 
        path = new address[](2);
        path[0]=_token_in;
        path[1] = _token_out;}
        else {
            path = new address[](3);
            path[0] = _token_in;
            path[1] = WETH_Goerli;
            path[2] = _token_out;
        }
        IUniswapV2Router(uniswap_goerli).swapExactTokensForTokens(_amountIn, _amountOutMin, path, _to, block.timestamp);
 }
       function getAmountOutMin(address _tokenIn, address _tokenOut, uint256 _amountIn) external view returns (uint256) {

        address[] memory path;
        if (_tokenIn == WETH_Goerli || _tokenOut == WETH_Goerli) {
            path = new address[](2);
            path[0] = _tokenIn;
            path[1] = _tokenOut;
        } else {
            path = new address[](3);
            path[0] = _tokenIn;
            path[1] = WETH_Goerli;
            path[2] = _tokenOut;
        }
        
        uint256[] memory amountOutMins = IUniswapV2Router(uniswap_goerli).getAmountsOut(_amountIn, path);
        return amountOutMins[path.length -1];}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, just my inattentiveness. I specified a wrong uniswap address in Goerli testnet.